# Node.js npm issue with installing packages

Tags: javascript, node.js

So after searching for the past 2 hours, around stackoverflow and Google, i decided i will post here.

The problem i am having is, i can't install any packages using npm. In this example i am trying to install jquery(also tried angular, express, gulp...) and i always get the same error:

```
49 error path C:\Users\fajfa\Desktop\Projects\Websites\generic-sites\travel- 
site\app\node_modules\jquery
50 error code ENOENT
51 error errno -4058
52 error syscall rename
53 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 
'C:\Users\fajfa\Desktop\Projects\Websites\generic-sites\travel- 
site\app\node_modules\jquery' -> 
'C:\Users\fajfa\Desktop\Projects\Websites\generic-sites\travel- 
site\app\node_modules\.jquery.DELETE'
54 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
55 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

This is taken from the generated log. I tried troubleshooting using this wiki:
https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting
Nothing works, reinstalled node.js, even installed 32bit version since one other person solved his issue this way. No difference. Ran cmd as admin, same error. Please help.

Adding to this issue:
Screenshot of the cmd: https://snag.gy/Nn3gMa.jpg
Screenshot of the json file: https://snag.gy/qHo0Qe.jpg

Comment: Are you running `npm i` in the same folder where there is the `package.json` file?

Comment: why didn't you show the command you used??

Comment: Ok i am sorry. I just use: npm install jquery
Also yes i am running where my .json file is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
npm cache clean
```

I ran into a similar problem and this helped me , Hope this helps

Comment: What is the version of your npm ?, If it is version v5 downgrade it to npm@5.3 @AnzeFajfar

Comment: So after one day for some reason it stopped working. Didn't change anything, tried to downgrade npm even more. Tried with npm 5.2.0, 5.1.0 same error message. I am adding the log i got today, i tried installing gulp-watch. https://file.io/tl3mIp. Also changed json file: https://snag.gy/rE8UHX.jpg, i am doing a tutorial so the person is using older versions.